# How to map multiple entities from LINQ query into a new entity using a common map method

Tags: c#, linq, dto

The following code is very similar to what I have in my solution, the difference is only that values for "entitiesA" and "entitiesB" collection are stored in a SQL Server database using LINQ data context. The code works perfects in the console application, but when values are retrieved from database, the system says "Could not translate expression '...' into SQL and could not treat it as a local expression.". What I'm doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace LinqSelectDemo
{
    class EntityA
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string StringValue { get; set; }
    }

    class EntityB
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int? EntityAID { get; set; }
        public int IntValue { get; set; }
    }

    class EntityC
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string StringValue { get; set; }
        public int IntValue { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static List<EntityA> entitiesA;

        static List<EntityB> entitiesB;

        static EntityC MapEntityC(EntityB entityB, EntityA entityA = null)
        {
            if (entityA == null)
            {
                entityA = entitiesA.FirstOrDefault(entity => (entity.ID == entityB.EntityAID));
            }
            return new EntityC()
            {
                ID = ((entityA != null) ? entityA.ID : 0) + ((entityB != null) ? entityB.ID : 0),
                StringValue = (entityA != null) ? entityA.StringValue : null,
                IntValue = (entityB != null) ? entityB.IntValue : int.MinValue
            };
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            entitiesA = new List<EntityA>()
            {
                new EntityA() { ID = 11, StringValue = "string1" },
                new EntityA() { ID = 12, StringValue = "string2" },
                new EntityA() { ID = 13, StringValue = "string3" },
            };
            entitiesB = new List<EntityB>()
            {
                new EntityB() { ID = 21, IntValue = 1, EntityAID = 11 },
                new EntityB() { ID = 22, IntValue = 2 },
                new EntityB() { ID = 23, IntValue = 3, EntityAID = 13 },
            };

            List<EntityC> entitiesC1 = entitiesB.GroupJoin(entitiesA, entityB => entityB.EntityAID, entityA => entityA.ID, (entityB, entityA) => new { entityB, entityA = entityA.SingleOrDefault() })
                                                .Select(entity => MapEntityC(entity.entityB, entity.entityA))
                                                .ToList();

            List<EntityC> entitiesC2 =
            (
                from entityB in entitiesB
                join entityA in entitiesA on entityB.EntityAID equals entityA.ID into tempEntitiesA
                from entityA in tempEntitiesA.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select MapEntityC(entityB, entityA)
            ).ToList();

            foreach (EntityC entityC in entitiesC1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}, StringValue: '{1}', IntValue: {2}", entityC.ID, entityC.StringValue, entityC.IntValue);
            };

            Console.WriteLine();

            foreach (EntityC entityC in entitiesC2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}, StringValue: '{1}', IntValue: {2}", entityC.ID, entityC.StringValue, entityC.IntValue);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In what line do you get that error?

Comment: In the queries to bind "entitiesC1" and "entitiesC2" when those entities came from database. (In the code for console application works perfectly)

Comment: firstly I would use Automapper for the entity mappings, secondly I wouldn't use any functions in LINQ to SQL expressions, this is where your issue is coming from. Evaluate the group join first (iterate over it with a `.ToList()`) now you will be working in memory, so map then.

Comment: I use a function because I don't want to repeat the mapping code in all service methods (here I only include one, but in the solution I have around 10 service methods that returns a list of EntityC from EntityA and EntityB tables). can you put some code slide of what you propose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to all of you for take a moment to write a possible solution and/or a comment. All ideas were fantastic. Actually the original code works as suppose to do it. The problem was that I was calling the mapping function not with trivial parameters but using a terciary operator expression. Something like:

```
Select(entity => MapEntityC(entity.entityB,
                           (entity.entityA != null) ? entity.entityA : new EntityA()));
```

That LINQ to SQL can't translate to SQL statement. As soon as I removed that expression and used a simple one, the code works. Once again thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be creating a `linq-to-objects` and `linq-to-entities` compatible query. Even though they appear similar, functionally they are completely different. So with that said, my proposed solution is going to ignore the `linq-to-objects` side of things.

---

First step is to create a class that holds both of our Entities. In this case `EntityA` and `EntityB`

```
public class EntityBandA
{
   public EntityB EntityB { get;set; }
   public EntityA EntityA { get;set; }
}
```

---

Now we need to create an `IQueryable` transformation method. The purpose of this method is to translate our new `IQueryable<EntityBandA>` into an `IQueryable<EntityC>`. Note - this will only run against the database once we iterate against it (ie `ToList`, `FirstOrDefault`, etc...).

```
static IQueryable<EntityC> MapEntityC(IQueryable<EntityBandA> query)
{
  var query = from e in query
              select new EntityC()
              {
                ID = e.EntityA.ID + e.EntityB,
                StringValue = e.EntityA.StringValue,
                IntValue = e.EntityB != null ? entityB.IntValue : int.MinValue
            };
  return query;
}
```

Notice that we removed some of the null checks. They are not necessary when using `linq-to-entities`, because our expression is being translated into sql. If no value is found, it will choose the default. (`Int:0, String:null`)

---

Now we need to adjust your current application to use our new method

```
IQueryable<EntityBandA> queryBandA = entitiesB.GroupJoin(entitiesA, entityB => entityB.EntityAID, entityA => entityA.ID, 
                                                 (entityB, entityA) => new EntityBandA 
                                                 { 
                                                    EntityB = entityB, 
                                                    EntityA = entityA.SingleOrDefault()
                                                 });

List<EntityC> entitiesC1 = MapEntityC(queryBandA).ToList();
```

Comment: Rather than call `Select` in your final query you can just construct the `EntityBandA `object in the `GroupJoin` selector.

Comment: An alternate design, which is of course merely a styalistic change, is to have a field/property that returns an `Expression<Func<EntityBandA, EntityC>>` rather than a method that takes an `IQueryable<EntityBandA>` and returns an `IQueryable<EntityC>`.  It would allow that projection to be used with other types of operators.

Comment: @Servy - Thank you for the suggestions. I really like the  `Expression<Func<EntityBandA, EntityC>>` idea.

Answer (score 0):

It means Linq To SQL cannot map your call to `MapEntity()` to an equal SQL expression.

You need to fetch data from Linq To SQL (maybe by querying a `VIEW` that contains your `JOIN`, that is easy to do) and, after you have received it and it is in memory (in a `List`), then map it to the `EntityC` data type.

**ALTERNATIVELY** You can just download the lists entitiesA and entitiesB by reading the whole tables into memory, something like this:

```
entitiesA = DbContext.EntitiesA.ToList();
entitiesB = DbContext.EntitiesB.ToList();
```

And then you can continue with the expressions that you have used, since you are now using in-memory lists and thus regular LINQ to Objects instead of LINQ to SQL.

Comment: If I remove the join from the LINQ query and pass only the "entityB" to the map function and "null" in the second parameter; it works but made another database access what is inefficient and I trying to avoid.

Comment: You can create a VIEW in SQL Server. That VIEW is essentially your LINQ query but formulated as SQL. Then you import that VIEW into LINQ to SQL (or Entity Framework, for that matter), and just query that from your C# code. This is much easier and the work is done inside the DB, which is also much faster.

Comment: Thank you but I can't create the view because I can't modify the context, I have to use what is there. What other solution came to your mind?

Comment: I've added the alternative solution to my answer.

Comment: As you well suggest, alternatively (I noted the emphasis) that is a solution, but is not practical due to table rows quantity (ten of thousands in each case). Do you know another approach to have a common mapping between service methods without have to repeat a lot of code?

Comment: Tens of thousands, is that such a problem? Supposing that each record takes 1K of memory, and each table has 75,000 rows, that is 150 MB of memory. That is not so much, is it?

Comment: 150 MB for a single query in a multiple postbacks binding, is a lot for not take that way unless no other solution or the context changes. Plus thousands or concurrent users, uhmmm... I prefer to avoid it. Anyway, thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: Obviously you would cache those tables in memory and re-use them.